# Worklight 5.0.6 - How to enable Java remote debugging?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, remote-debugging, embedded-jetty, worklight-studio

I would like to debug the server part of my Worklight application (java). AFAIK Worklight 5.0.6 uses an embedded Jetty HTTP server. I wonder how it's possible to enable remote debugging for this process so I can set breakpoints, watch scope variables and so on?

Thank you in advance,
spyro

Comment: Is this question resolved?

Answer (score 0):

In Worklight 5.0.6, where the Jetty application server is used, Java debugging is not possible.

A possible solution, in case you are an IBM Worklight customer is to deploy Worklight on WAS Liberty, where you should be able to do this.